# Tengo un problema con el operador scan de rxjs, el resultado es una secuencia con NaN

Tags: rxjs

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código que genera un enemigo cada 1.5 seg.

Es una sequencia infinita con rxjs.

```
// generate an element each 1.5 seg.
const enemies$ = interval(1500)
    .pipe(
        /* 
        use scan to convert each integer of the interval
        into an enemy appears outside of the screen.
          first emit [enemy]
          second emit [enemy, enemy]
          n emit [enemy, enemy ...... enemy]
        */
        scan( (enemyArray) => {
        // console.log(enemyArray);
        if (!Array.isArray(enemyArray)) {
            enemyArray = [];
        }
        // i replace canvas.width with 100.
        let enemy = {
            x: parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10),
            y: -30
        };
        console.log(enemy);
        enemyArray.push({...enemy});
        console.log(enemyArray);
        return [ ...enemyArray];
    }, [])
)
```

El resultado en la consola es siguiente

```
un elemento
   {
     x: 1411
     y: -30
   }
```

el array que resulta es

```
 [{x: NaN, y: 8045}]
```

Uso ese array para dibujar los enemigos en el canvas.

No sé porque cuando añado el enemy a enemyArray. se guarda como NaN.
Ayuda porfavor